# Clarify the Low Quality Posts review queue for answers

Tags: discussion, review

In the LQP review queue, some of the answers meet the criteria for flagging for moderator attention.  Some are not flaggable but rather involve quality issues that moderators are not expected to deal with.  I'm focusing here on answers that can't be improved or aren't worth the effort because they contain nothing of real value.

In general, downvotes are the solution for poor answers.  It isn't clear whether poor quality that does not meet the flagging criteria can also be a basis for deletion.  The explanation on the Trusted User Privilege help page as to the criteria for deletion is a bit nebulous but generally conforms with the flagging criteria.

Which is the purpose of this queue:

- To simply delegate moderator functions, adhering to the same set of deletion criteria.  The imperfect bot also identifies some poor answers that aren't deletable under flagging criteria and these are largely not supposed to be deleted.
- To help keep the site clean of poor quality posts; the bot is purposely targeting non-flaggable, low quality answers for possible deletion solely on that basis.

Should I be recommending deletion for bot-identified answers just on the basis of poor quality (a sort of "no-cost downvote" for a hopeless answer), or should deletion recommendations be limited to answers that meet flaggable criteria?

Comment: Well then thank the bot for pointing out the more likely and give the people the benifit of the doubt and chance to participate when possible.  That may include prodding them and editing also.